# Adding the value of two columns in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a debit and a credit column. If there is a value in the debit, the credit will be blank and vice versa. I am trying to calculate a net amount column which is debit - credit

I am using the following:

(Total:+NZ([debit],0)-nz([credit],0))

The full query looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO T_RECON ( REFERENCE, RECDATE, NET_AMOUNT, PROPID )
SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, NET_AMOUNT, PROPID
FROM (SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, (Total:+NZ([debit],0)-nz([credit],0)), PROPID
  FROM LEDGER_1
  WHERE PERIOD = 13 AND LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '55971'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, (Total:+NZ([debit],0)-nz([credit],0)), PROPID
  FROM LEDGER_2
  WHERE PERIOD = 13 AND LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '55971'
);
```

I am hoping to just see the debit - credit display in the `NET_AMOUNT` field. However, on the above I am getting a SYNTAX error. My query works just fine when I exclude the `NET_AMOUNT` part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to see the full error message.  But I think you need to give a name to the column in the subquery and the subquery itself:

```
INSERT INTO T_RECON ( REFERENCE, RECDATE, NET_AMOUNT, PROPID )
SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, NET_AMOUNT, PROPID
FROM (SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, (Total:+NZ([debit],0)-nz([credit],0)) AS NET_AMOUNT, PROPID
  FROM LEDGER_1
  WHERE PERIOD = 13 AND LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '55971'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT REFERENCE, RECDATE, (Total:+NZ([debit],0)-nz([credit],0)), PROPID
  FROM LEDGER_2
  WHERE PERIOD = 13 AND LEDGER_ACCOUNT = '55971'
) AS QRY;
```

Comment: Hmmm...`Total:` actually works in Access SQL? Cannot be unless quoted in a concatenated string expression.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Access' Design View and SQL View for assigning calculated columns. SQL column aliases need the `AS` operator after expression not colon separator before expression. And be sure column alias corresponds to outer level query column name:

```
SELECT ... NZ([debit],0)-NZ([credit],0) AS NET_AMOUNT, ...
```

You can use colon approach in design view and it will *translate* with `AS` operator in sql view. Place below in query cell:

```
NET_AMOUNT: NZ([debit],0)-NZ([credit],0)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much